# java - Apache CXF modify header element prefix in SOAP request

Tags: java, soap, cxf

I'm using Apache CXF to consume WSDL when talking to my server.
Each SOAP message has header element to add support for ws-security. The problem is my header element is generated in a weird way:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
   <env:Header xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
   ...
   </env:Header>
   <soap:Body xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="id-82d2a06c-4f23-4c0d-adc7-35acdb59cc90">
      ....
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

It uses wrong prefix, `env` instead of `soap`.
Server expects the header to be in this format:

```
<soap:Header xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
```

but gets this instead

```
<env:Header xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
```

I don't really know what part of the code I should post, here is how I configure my `JaxWsProxyFactoryBean`:

```
JaxWsProxyFactoryBean jaxWsProxyFactoryBean = new JaxWsProxyFactoryBean();
// Set SOAP 1.2 binding
final Soap12 soap12 = Soap12.getInstance();
BindingConfiguration config = new BindingConfiguration() {
    @Override
    public String getBindingId() {
        return soap12.getBindingId();
    }
};


jaxWsProxyFactoryBean.setBindingConfig(config);
jaxWsProxyFactoryBean.setBindingId(soap12.getBindingId());

jaxWsProxyFactoryBean.setServiceClass(Oppslagstjeneste1602.class);
jaxWsProxyFactoryBean.setAddress(serviceAddress);

// Configures WS-Security
WSS4JInterceptorHelper.addWSS4JInterceptors(jaxWsProxyFactoryBean);
contactInfoPort = (ConnectService) jaxWsProxyFactoryBean.create();
```

What can I do to change to namespace to `soap`??

Comment: The namespaces are exactly the same, only the prefixes are different. If the server is not processing them correctly, that seems like the server's problem. Do you have any control over the server?

Comment: No, I don't have control over it, is it possible to change the prefix?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30081435/change-the-prefix-in-cxf-with-interceptor